# Azure Container Instance doesn't forward requests to container

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot project to azure using docker containers.

If I do `az container logs --name ... --resource-group ...` I see

> Tomcat started on port(s): 80 (http) with context path ''

`az container show --name ... --resource-group ...`

```json
"ipAddress": {
    "dnsNameLabel": "X",
    "dnsNameLabelReusePolicy": "Unsecure",
    "fqdn": "X.centralus.azurecontainer.io",
    "ip": "Y",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 80,
        "protocol": "TCP"
      }
    ],
    "type": "Public"
  },
```

Now if I go to `X.centralus.azurecontainer.io` I only see `404 page not found` and don't see any request being made in the logs for the spring container (have logs set to debug to see if it serves anything)

On the azure portal it also confirms that my container is in state "Running"

For what reasons does "page not found" show instead of just forwarding to the container on the same port? Anyone know what could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you please check is it running on Local container or not before trying it in ACI?

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT It worked perfectly locally, I ended up deleting the container instance a couple more times and re-running the CI deploy job and it ended up working magically after 2 times. No change on my part, so I assume it was an Azure bug (especially since the CI job is just the default ACI one so nothing weird going on there).

Comment: Glad your issue got resolve by itslef.

Answer (score -3):

•   I would highly recommend you to please refer to the below Microsoft documentation links for troubleshooting common Azure Spring cloud application deployment issues and in general issues faced while deploying an Azure Container Instance. As they are quite helpful in resolving the common issues faced by users regarding Azure Container Instances.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/troubleshoot

Comment: hi, this is unhelpful, I had already looked at basically all the troubleshooting guide and then answer ended up being to just re-make everything.